# Creating Lua globals in Objective C/C from userdata

Tags: objective-c, ios, lua

I am working on a library to allow Lua (5.2) scripting of games in iOS 5.x.  I have created a class and added bindings to allow it to be created and accessed form Lua.  The C initializer method called from Lua is given below:

```
static int newGeminiObject(lua_State *L){
    GeminiObject *go = [[GeminiObject alloc] initWithLuaState:L];

    GeminiObject **lgo = (GeminiObject **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(GeminiObject *));
    *lgo = go;

    luaL_getmetatable(L, GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_setuservalue(L, -2);

    NSLog(@"New GeminiObject created");

    // add this new object to the globall list of objects
    [[Gemini shared].geminiObjects addObject:go];

    return 1;

}
```

This assigns a metatable which is set up elsewhere to provide access to various methods.  Additionally, it attaches a table as a uservalue to allow script code to assign attributes to the objects.

I can create these objects in Lua scripts with no problem:

```
require "gemini"
x = gemini.new()
x:addEventListener("touch", objectTouched)
```

Here objectTouched is a a Lua method defined elsewhere that handles a touch event.  Here `addEventListener` binds it to `touch` events.

These objects work just fine.  When I attempt to create one from C, however, I am running into problems.  I can create the object, but trying to assign it to a global and then invoke it in a script fails.

The following C code runs

```
-(void) addRuntimeObject {
    GeminiObject *rt = [[GeminiObject alloc] initWithLuaState:L];
    GeminiObject **lruntime = (GeminiObject **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(GeminiObject *));
    *lruntime = rt;

    // set the metatable - effectively declaring the type for this object
    luaL_getmetatable(L, GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

    // add a table to hold anything the user wants to add
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_setuservalue(L, -2);

    // create an entry in the global table
    lua_setglobal(L, "Runtime");

    // empty the stack
    lua_pop(L, lua_gettop(L));
}
```

This should define a global named "Runtime".  Trying to access this variable from a script like this

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame)
```

Results in the following error:

`attempt to index global 'Runtime' (a userdata value)`

It is a userdata value, but this doesn't seem to matter when I create one in Lua directly.  The metatable binding provides access to the methods and metamethods.  Again, this works fine if the object is created from Lua, just not when it is created in C.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here, or what the correct way to make a global from userdata is?

EDIT

Based on comments below regarding confusion about GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY, I thought I would list the code that is actually used in the binding:

```
static const struct luaL_Reg geminiObjectLib_f [] = {
    {"new", newGeminiObject},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

static const struct luaL_Reg geminiObjectLib_m [] = {
    {"addEventListener", addEventListener},
    {"__gc", geminiObjectGC},
    {"__index", l_irc_index},
    {"__newindex", l_irc_newindex},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_geminiObjectLib (lua_State *L){
    // create the metatable and put it into the registry
    luaL_newmetatable(L, GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY);

    lua_pushvalue(L, -1); // duplicates the metatable


    luaL_setfuncs(L, geminiObjectLib_m, 0);

    // create a table/library to hold the functions
    luaL_newlib(L, geminiObjectLib_f);

    NSLog(@"gemini lib opened");

    return 1;
}
```

This code registers the library of functions (not show here) that provide the methods and metamethods for the `GeminiObjects`.  The call to `luaL_newmetatable` creates a new metatable and associates it in the registry with the key `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY`.  `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY` is just a unique string defined in the header.  `luaL_setfuncs` actually adds the function pointers to the metatable, making them available as methods of the objects.

Comment: You really should break the object setup stuff out into a function; copy&paste coding is bad. Also, how does `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY` work? It won't be in the same place all the time. Not unless you pushed it onto the stack (and even then, it won't *necessarily* be where you think it is).

Comment: After thinking about it, my guess is that it has something to do with this mysterious `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY` thing. You seem to have gotten the wrong table and set a `nil` value into your userdata's metatable.

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you for your comment, but I'm not sure why you think my code is not in functions.  Clearly I have listed two functions here, `newGeminiObject` a C function following the standard prototype for C functions invoked by Lua, and `addRuntimeObject`, an Objective C function that creates the single instance of the `Runtime` object.  Also, there is no cut-and-paste code here, so I don't know why you mentioned that.  Regarding `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY`, this is a constant that is used in a separate method when setting up the metatable for this object type.  This is standard stuff.

Comment: "Also, there is no cut-and-paste code here" The first seven lines of code are *identical*, except for different variable names. That could easily be put into a function called "CreateGeminiOnLuaStack".

Comment: "I'm not sure why you think my code is not in functions." Because you call `initWithLuaState`, which is not a function you've shown. This may be modifying the Lua state; I don't know what it does because you didn't include it. Therefore, I can only guess what it does.

Comment: "Regarding `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY`, this is a constant that is used in a separate method when setting up the metatable for this object type." Yes, and that's probably why it isn't working. The index passed to `luaL_getmetatable` can be either a stack index, `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX`, or an upvalue for the function currently being called. If `GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY` really is an upvalue, then you're supposed to get it with `lua_upvalueindex` to get it. However, you can only access that upvalue when the specific function you registered with it is called. Upvalues are stored with functions.

Comment: Re: the first seven lines, I only put code into a separate function if it is used in more than two places.  This code is used in exactly two places.  Re: GEMINI_OBJECT_LUA_KEY, you are correct.  This was a mistake.  If you would care to put your answer in an answer response in stead of a comment, I will gladly up vote it.

Comment: Wait a bit on posting that answer.  You are incorrect about `luaL_getmetatable`.  You are describing `lua_getmetatable`.  `luaL_getmetatable` takes a constant string as its last argument.  The same string used to create the metatable in the call to `luaL_newmetatable`.  Back to square one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is still interested, I got the answer to my question from the kind folks on the Lua mailing list. The problem here is that the library binding function `luaopen_geminiObjectLib` is not called before my call to `addRuntimeObject`.

Since iOS does not support dynamic libraries, I had added my libraries in statically by adding pointers to them to the `preloadedlibs` array in `linit.c` of the Lua source.  Unfortunately, libraries added this way are not loaded until `require('libname')` is executed in a Lua script.  Since I was calling my `addRuntimeObject` method prior to executing the Lua script, the library was not yet loaded.

The solution is to add the pointer to `luaopen_geminiObjectLib` to the `loadedlibs` array in the same `linit.c` file.  This causes the library to be loaded when Lua starts up with no need for scripts to `require` it.